# Error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'headers') in next.js api

Tags: javascript, mysql, next.js, next.js13

I'd like to fetch data from mysql in in next.js api so in `api/posts/routes.js` I have:

import { NextResponse } from "next/server"

```
import {db} from "@/utils/db.js"
 
 

export const GET = () => {
           const q = `SELECT * FROM posts`
            db.query(q, (err, data)=>{
            if (err) {
                return NextResponse.json({ error: 'Internal Server Error' }, { status: 500 })
            } 
            return NextResponse.json({ data })
     
        })
   
     }
```

where `utils/db.js` is:

```
import mysql from "mysql"

export const db = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "127.0.0.1",
    user: "nextuser",
    password: "supersecret",
    database: "nextdb"
})
```

I have already created the database and `posts` table,
But I get this error in the terminal:

```
- error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'headers')
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./node_modules/.pnpm/next@13.4.6_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/next/dist/server/future/route-modules/app-route/module.js:277:61)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
```

While in the browser I get this error:

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/posts net::ERR_ABORTED 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

I fetch the data in component like this:

```
async function getData() {
  const res = await fetch("/api/posts",   {
    mode: 'cors',
    headers: {
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*'
    }
  },
  {next: {
    revalidate: 10
  }})
  if (!res.ok) {
    // This will activate the closest `error.js` Error Boundary
    console.log('error response', res)
    return notFound()
  }
   return res.json()
}
 
 
const Blog = async () => {
  const data = await getData()
  ...
```